# Follow-up email to submit my Cv

Tags: graduate-admissions

I've sent an email to a potential supervisor and I've gotten an email today from the chair of Graduate Studies that says "we would be very pleased to accept you". Now what should I do? in my first email I've just talked about my interest and how it would be an excellent fit to the supervisor's research interests. I think I should send my CV this time, but to whom? The supervisor or The chair of Graduate Studies?

Comment: What else did the chair of Graduate Studies say in the e-mail?

Comment: @scaaahu In my answer, I though the Chair did just say that, but I agree, the message seems a bit short !

Comment: @GautierC The e-mail from the Graduate Studies is very odd. Usually, an admission letter will ask the recipient to acknowledge the offer and would tell the student what to do next, such as how and when to complete the paper work, etc. I think there is something missing in the question

Comment: @scaaahu agree. In fact, let's wait for OP, he'll tell us what is it about. But yeah, usually it's like "we are glad to tell you that your blablabla... then you have to fill that and this, and don't forget to be here at 11' for the interview.

Answer (score 2):

> I've sent an email to a potential supervisor and I've gotten an email today from the chair of Graduate Studies that says "we would be very pleased to accept you".

That mean the potential supervisor forwarded your email to the Chair of Graduate Studies.

> Now what should I do? in my first email I've just talked about my interest and how it would be an excellent fit to the supervisor's research interests. I think I should send my CV this time, but to whom? The supervisor or The chair of Graduate Studies?

Since they want to work with you, the best thing is to **ask them** about what is next. Send an email to the Chair of Graduate Studies (since it seems it's their job), asking for what is next etc...